# Database design for ecommerce pricing

Tags: database-design

I have designed an ecommerce database with `products` table to store product data

```
products (id, name, price, discount, discounted_price, tax_rate)
```

Here the `price` is including tax, `discount` is again including tax, `discounted_price` is including tax as well.

e.g, the `price` of product is `299`, `discount` is `100` and the `discounted_price` is `199` with a `tax rate` of `5%`.

In the `orders` table, the order is stored as

```
orders (id, sub_total, discount, tax_amount, total)
```

Here I am storing price before discount pre tax in `sub_total`, discount is storing pre tax, tax amount is stored in `tax_amount` and finally total amount with tax is stored in `total`

Now the issue here is that the price stored to customer is `with tax`. Also the discount is shown `with tax` but is saved as discount pre tax in orders database and if we generate invoice for the order, it gets data from `orders` table and shows a different discount amount.

How to fix this so that we have consistent pricing in `products` as well as `orders` table. Please note that I want to show `price including tax` to the customer, but the same cannot be stored in final orders table as we need to make account of taxes.

Comment: Easy -- don't store `product.price`, `product.discount` etc. with tax included; calculate amounts as and when needed.

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with database design. It is just an issue with having two different modes of encoding prices, with and without tax. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with that, as long as you know which numbers are with tax and which are not. You could begin by naming them accordingly so the difference is clear.

Or you could make it so that all prices in all tables are always with tax. Or without tax. Or even have tables hold two copies, with and without tax. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

From a database and application design point of view, create a separate pricing table that holds the base price, tax rate, and any discounts. This table should link to the products table through a product ID. The structure could be:

```
pricing (product_id, base_price, tax_rate, discount, start_date, end_date)
```

This approach separates the concerns of product information and pricing. The products table will hold product-related data (like name, description, etc.), while the pricing table manages all pricing details. Also allows some flexibility by allowing you to carry prices for periods and tracking changes on product prices.

- You can calculate the final price (including tax) on the fly for
  customer display and store the pre-tax price and discount in the
  orders table.
- It allows you not to hit a product table when all you require is
  pricing information for accounting purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

In the products table:

- In the 3 columns (price, discount and discounted_price) do not
  include tax when saving data.
- Add 3 new columns (price_including_tax, discount_including_tax
  and discounted_price_including_tax) and in these columns include tax when saving data.